# mysqli query with mysql function inside

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to produce a passfrase on the database with a function I found somewere.
If i use the sql query directly on the database it produces a string as desired, but in my php page it gives the **error**:

> "**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array()
>   on boolean"

```
$query_rsCaptchaID = "DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `randomPasswordGenerator` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `randomPasswordGenerator`(
  ) RETURNS varchar(64) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  DECLARE charCount TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE charDiceRoll TINYINT(2);
  DECLARE randomChar CHAR(1);
  DECLARE randomPassword CHAR(64) DEFAULT '';
  REPEAT
    SET charCount = charCount + 1;
    SET charDiceRoll = 1 + FLOOR(RAND() * 94);
    IF (charDiceRoll <= 32)
    THEN
      SET randomChar = ELT(charDiceRoll,
      '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^',
      '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '=', '_', '+',
      '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\', '/', '|', '?',
      ';', ':', '\'', '\"', ',', '.', '<', '>');
    ELSEIF (charDiceRoll >= 33)
      AND (charDiceRoll <= 68)
    THEN
      SET charDiceRoll = charDiceRoll - 33;
      SET randomChar = CONV(
        charDiceRoll,
        10, 36);
    ELSE
      SET charDiceRoll = charDiceRoll - 59;
      SET randomChar = LOWER(
        CONV(
          charDiceRoll,
          10, 36)
      );
    END IF;
    SET randomPassword = CONCAT(randomPassword, randomChar);
  UNTIL (charCount = 64)
  END REPEAT;
  RETURN randomPassword;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
SELECT randomPasswordGenerator() AS captchaID;";
$rsCaptchaID = mysqli_query($db,$query_rsCaptchaID);
$row_rsCaptchaID = $rsCaptchaID->fetch_array();
```

Any ideas anyone? I´m quite new on MySQLi, and not english speaking, sorry for errors.

Comment: `is_a` function has been deprecated for a long time (PHP 5.0). Use `instanceof` operator instead.

Comment: I took the way thru php: `code`function random_str($length,$keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}\\/|?;:\'\",.<>') {
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    if ($max < 1) {
        throw new Exception('$keyspace must be at least two characters long');
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return $str;
}

$colname_captchaID = random_str(64);

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because your query fails. Between the last two lines you posted, you need to do some error checking:

```
$rsCaptchaID = mysqli_query($db,$query_rsCaptchaID);
if(!$rsCaptchaID) die(mysqli_error($db); // <- will show you the SQL error
$row_rsCaptchaID = $rsCaptchaID->fetch_array();
```

Comment: I always think its better to do `if($rsCaptchaID === false)` as `$rsCaptchaID` just might look false because its not a scalar variable. But I guess its just a personal choise

Comment: @RiggsFolly I also tend to use `=== false` in my own code to build good habits. In this instance though there is no possibility of this failing because `mysqli_query` can only return `true`, `false`, or a resource (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). Only a legitimate error can reach `die`

Comment: My point is that when its a resource, it might just possibly look like a false!

Comment: I don't think so @RiggsFolly . Objects with properties are truthy. Even empty objects unless your PHP is a decade old.  See this fiddle https://3v4l.org/7XTco.  For the docs, see the section `Converting to boolean`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: Interesting reading

Comment: Thanks @BeetleJuice! I think I´ll give it up as a query and do the passfrase in php insted...

Comment: @DavidSundberg I think that's a good idea. I appreciate the thanks: upvote and/or selecting the answer would be even better. Happy coding.